# Как перенести Laravel проект на простой хостинг?

Tags: php, laravel, хостинг, hosting

У меня есть ftp доступ к хостингу, на который мне нужно залить Laravel проект. В public_html я закинул сам проект(my_laravel) и папку my_laravel/public.
Структура выглядит так -
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В index.php прописано

```
    define('LARAVEL_START', microtime(true));
    require __DIR__.'/my_laravel/vendor/autoload.php';
    $app = require_once __DIR__.'/my_laravel/bootstrap/app.php';
$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);

$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
);

$response->send();

$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

В htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Но при этом на сайте вылетает ошибка 500. Подскажите, что я делаю не так?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.S. Как я понял, ошибка возникает на этой строке. С чем это может быть связано?

```
$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
);
```

Comment: Права доступа может не дали, раз апач у вас - смотрите там в логах

Comment: @YaroslavMolchan ну мои проекты на WP и Joomla работают, не думаю что проблема в правах доступа(если я Вас правильно понял). Логи я посмотреть не могу, в папке logs лежит 2 ярлыка ***.com.error.log и .com.log , которые некуда не ведут.

Comment: @YaroslavMolchan ошибка происходит на этапе `$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
);`. Не знаете с чем это может быть связано?

Comment: Трейс покажите, то что вы показали ничего не дает.

Comment: @YaroslavMolchan , можете пожалуйста уточнить что Вы имеете ввиду?

Comment: Трейс ошибки с логов апача, или логов storage/logs, если они там есть

Comment: @YaroslavMolchan storage/logs есть,но там пусто. Получается это проблема сервера, а не кода?

Comment: Возможно вы не включили логи, или включите вывод ошыбок, сайт соравно лежит)

Comment: @UKRman в .env прописано APP_DEBUG=true, я так понимаю это за логи и отвечает. А как включить вывод ошибок?

Comment: Получается не доходят логи до приложения, нужно смотреть логи апача

Comment: Пробовали очистить кэш? Есть же в [доках это всё](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/deployment)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте изменить `Options -MultiViews -Indexes` на `Options -Indexes`, в некоторых случаях это исправит проблему.

Answer (score 0):

В public_html должно находиться то что лежит в вашей папке laravel_app/public, то есть вам нужно сделать ссылку с папки public_html на public. Соответственно само приложение laravel должно быть на уровень выше папки public_html